# How to create buttons and alow specifying any string

Tags: c#, botframework

Is there a way to show a question, with buttons, and allow the user to wither pick one of the buttons or specify a different answer?

For instance, have the bot ask: "how can I help you today?"
the specify buttons with: "Get on a diet, find a good hotel, learn English" and then let the user either pick one of these, or just way something different such as: "I would like to get to the moon".

We are currently using:

```
PromptDialog.Choice(context, OnMenuOptionSelected, m_requestTypes, "Here's what I can do for you", descriptions: m_requestTypes.Select(t => t.GetDescription()));
```

In case the user types in text that does not match the buttons it would show the question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely doable but not with the out-of-the-box `PromptChoice`. What you would have to do is to inherit from it, override the `TryParse` and add your custom logic, to either pass-through any response you receive or just the ones you want.

The [CancelablePromptChoice](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers.BotAssets/Dialogs/CancelablePromptChoice.cs) from the [ContosoFlowers](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers) sample shows this approach, in this case, to accept terms to quit from the `PromptChoice`.

Answer (score 0):

I can show you how I do this in node.js. You can probably port it to C#:

- http://www.pveller.com/smarter-conversations-part-3-breadcrumbs/#Relaxed-Prompt

The idea is to make sure that Bot Framework doesn't re-prompt if the answer is not one of the options (buttons) provided.